# Area of common surface of two bubble

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, fluid-dynamics, surface-tension

What will be the area of common surface of two identical bubbles of radius R , i know there surface will be flat but i am unable to figure out how to start
Pressure will be same on both sides 
So net force will be zero , but how i relate it to area

Comment: I'm not sure what you're talking about.  Is it two bubbles that are connected or pressing up against each other?

Comment: @JMac the two bubble are identical in shape when they came closer to each other then they will share a common surface (circle) we have to find to find the area of surface , my attempt is that they will tries to minimize their potential energy and hence the contact area

Comment: What is bringing them together? What are the properties of the bubbles themselves?  Unless there's something I'm missing; there isn't nearly enough information to solve this.

Comment: There cohesive forces bringing together

Comment: Have a read of https://thatsmaths.com/2015/01/22/plateaus-problem-and-double-bubbles/ and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_bubble_conjecture

Comment: Now the problemis how we can find the minimum  area of circle formed by two spherical bubbles , for a fixed volume

Comment: Why no love for this question? It seems to me really interesting. It is presumably a tradeoff of the reduction in surface energy and the increase in pressure of the bubbles.

Comment: @JohnRennie The problem I see is that without more information on what these bubbles are; there's no clear answer.  Consider the difference between water bubbles and hollow steel bubbles. (extreme example; but it fits with what we're told).  IMO, this question could easily be fluid mechanics or contact mechanics; without more information we don't even know the best method to solve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is [double bubble theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_bubble_conjecture), and it was a surprisingly difficult thing to prove. [The general proof was only completed in 2002](http://www.jstor.org/stable/3062123). The theorem states that the shape the two bubbles adopt minimises the total surface area.

Having said this, neither the Wikipedia article I linked above nor [the Wolfram article](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DoubleBubble.html) give the equation for the radius of the disk between the bubbles. Hopefully with the information here you'll be able to pin this down for yourself.

Comment: I am in 11 standard so i Don't have much know knowledge of advance topic , if that question can be solved using simple mechanics